# Why Php Assumes No Session Started When It Has Been Started?

Tags: php, session

Php Folks,

Why on the second-page load (same page), the ELSEIF does not trigger?

My Expectation:
On the 1st page load, the IF should trigger since there are no sessions at the beginning.

Then a session should start. Set to `'$_SESSION['form_step'] = 'start'`.

Finally, set to:

```
$_SESSION['form_step'] = 'end';
```

On the 2nd page load (same page reloaded), the `ELSEIF` should trigger since a session was started previously and set to: `$_SESSION['form_step'] = 'end'`.

```
if(!session_id() || $_SESSION['form_step'] != 'end') 
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['form_step'] = 'start';
    echo "Line: 28 "; echo "Session Step: "; echo $_SESSION['form_step']; echo "<br>";
    echo "Line: 29 "; echo "New Session Id: "; echo session_id(); echo "<br>";
    $_SESSION['form_step'] = 'end';
}
elseif($_SESSION['form_step'] == 'end') 
{
    echo "Line: 35 "; echo "Session Step: "; echo $_SESSION['form_step']; echo "<br>";
    echo "Line: 36 "; echo "New Session Id: "; echo session_id(); echo "<br>";
}
```

Result:

On the second page-load or same page reload, even though a session exists, the `ELSEIF` doesn't trigger but the `IF` triggers instead as if there were no sessions in existence or no sessions were started previously or no sessions been started yet.
Why is that? When you test the code you will see:
On the 1st page load, the `IF` will trigger.
So far, so good.

But refreshing the page would result in the same `IF` getting triggered again instead of the `ELSEIF`!
Not good!
Puzzling. I am confused.
On every page reload, I get echoed the same:

```
Line: 28 Session Step: start 
Line: 29 New Session Id: ri4pbr42623g9uoaiiq3ebr41r
```

**EDIT 1**
I edited code to following based on Alvaro Gonzales and Ben Foster advice:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();

if(!session_id() || session_id() != $session_id || $_SESSION['form_step'] != 'end') 
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['form_step'] = 'start';
    echo "Line: 28 "; echo "Session Step: "; echo $_SESSION['form_step']; echo "<br>";
    echo "Line: 29 "; echo "New Session Id: "; echo session_id(); echo "<br>";
    $_SESSION['form_step'] = 'end';
    $session_id = session_id();
}
elseif($_SESSION['form_step'] == 'end') //Q2. WHY THIS IF GETS TRIGGERED WHEN CLICKING ANY NUMBERED PAGE LINKS (ON PAGINATION SECTION (EG PAGE 1 2 3 ETC.)) SINCE SESSION ID ALREADY EXISTS DUE TO ['form_step'] = 'end' ?
{
    echo "Line: 35 "; echo "Session Step: "; echo $_SESSION['form_step']; echo "<br>";
    echo "Line: 36 "; echo "New Session Id: "; echo session_id(); echo "<br>";
}
```

I now get this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: session_id in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\power.page\pagination_test_SIMPLE.php on line 5
>
> Notice: session_start(): A session had already been started - ignoring
> in C:\xampp\htdocs\power.page\pagination_test_SIMPLE.php on line 7**

Along with the error, I get my echoes:

```
Line: 28 Session Step: start
Line: 29 New Session Id: s3sojmnogkhkmga43fhk1u2j17**
```

How to fix this without seeing errors?
NOTE: At the very 1st time the page loads, I need to the IF to get triggered so it finds no sessions and creates one.

```
Sets $_SESSION['form_step'] = 'start';
Then $_SESSION['form_step'] = 'end';
```

Then when I reload the page, I need PHP to find the `$_SESSION['form_step'] == 'end'` and trigger the `IFELSE` and not the same `IF` again.

Why I need the `ELSEIF` triggered on the page reload? is because when the page is reloaded I need task 2 to trigger. While when the page is loaded for the 1st time I need task 1 to trigger.

`IF` deals with task 1. `ElseIF` deals with task 2.
This is a complex script. I only gave a relevant snippet here.

**EDIT 2**
If I leave the `IF` to this:

```
if(!session_id())
```

Then the IF never triggers. Always the `ELSE`.
I need the IF to trigger on the very 1st time the page loads and initiate the session and do the 1st task.
Then as long as the session exists, on every page refresh/reload, I need the `ELSEIF` to trigger to do the 2nd task.
This code doesn't work ...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();

if(!session_id()) 
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['form_step'] = 'start';
    echo "Line: 28 "; echo "Session Step: "; echo $_SESSION['form_step']; echo "<br>";
    echo "Line: 29 "; echo "New Session Id: "; echo session_id(); echo "<br>";
    $_SESSION['form_step'] = 'end';
    $session_id = session_id();
}
elseif($_SESSION['form_step'] == 'end')
{
    echo "Line: 35 "; echo "Session Step: "; echo $_SESSION['form_step']; echo "<br>";
    echo "Line: 36 "; echo "New Session Id: "; echo session_id(); echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: `session_start();` is what populates `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 2):

`session_start()` needs to be called before attempting to access any session variable, even when refreshing the page.

So when refreshing the page, a session is not currently active. Hence your if statement evaluates to true.

Try moving `session_start()` to the top of your file.

Comment: Ben Foster,

But since I started the session at the very 1st time the page loads and did not unset or destroy the session, then when I load the page a 2nd time, why is not the session still available ? What is unsetting it or destroying it ? That is my big question.
Also, would I not get the error, on my page reload, that a session had already started ?

Comment: @TigerCoder The session **is** available. It's simply what PHP won't load it by default, just like it won't fetch data from a database by default.

Comment: @Ben Foster,

I did ask you people asked. I get error. I updated my original post. See heading "EDIT". - Thank you!

Comment: @Alvaro Gonzalez,
Thanks for the answer. But can you show me a code sample, if you don't mind, on how to achieve my purpose ? I mentioned my purpose on my original post under heading "EDIT". - Thank You!

Comment: @TigerCoder Your code runs from top to bottom. You read `$session_id` in line 6 and you define its value in line 12.

Comment: @Alvaro Gonzalez,
Kindly show me a fix then to achieve my purpose which I mentioned on "EDIT 1" because I'm going in circles for 2 nights now.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is very unclear to me. But this should work (based on my understanding of the expected behavior).

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['form_step']) || $_SESSION['form_step'] !== 'end') {
    // This will be overwrited before the end of this page load.
    $_SESSION['form_step'] = 'start';
    echo "Line: ".__LINE__;
    echo "Session Step: ";
    echo $_SESSION['form_step'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Line: ".__LINE__;
    echo "New Session Id: ";
    echo session_id();
    echo "<br>";
    $_SESSION['form_step'] = 'end';
    // This variable is never used, you might want to get rid of it.
    $session_id = session_id();
} else {
    echo "Line: ".__LINE__;
    echo "Session Step: ";
    echo $_SESSION['form_step'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Line: ".__LINE__;
    echo "New Session Id: ";
    echo session_id();
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Julien B,

I tested your code. It is triggering the IF on the 1st round of the page load.
Then it is triggering the ELSE on all other rounds of the same page load. That is what I wanted!
Thanks!
Now, I will integrate my code tomorrow and see if your code works or not. It should! Thanks very much!
If it doesn't work, then I'll get back to you!
Cheers!